# How to replace SKU with a custom attribute on the frontend

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, sku

our product has SKU and P/N number. All product's SKU has the same, but the P/N will depend on the country, so I've created an attribute "P/N" and want to show P/N on the product page instead of SKU.

It is possible to replace SKU on the frontend with P/N?

can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Hi @eric, Have you tried my solution? If it helped, please upvote and accept my answer so that others can also get benefitted from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note:** I have not tried it yet but it should work.

To show the SKU value in the product view page, **`/vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml`** file is called.

In this file you will find code like below:

```
$_call = $block->getAtCall();
$_code = $block->getAtCode();
```

which basically gets the values from the default **`catalog_product_view.xml`** file, there is a code block like below:

```
<arguments>
    <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getSku</argument>
    <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
    <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
    <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">default</argument>
    <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="sku"</argument>
</arguments>
```

You can override **`catalog_product_view.xml`** in your theme and change the values of **at_call**, **at_code**, **css_class**, **at_label**, and **add_attribute** as per your requirement.

Comment: Hello, Mohit, Please help me https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/277688/magento-2-3-1-sorry-but-you-can-only-add-maximum-quantity-of-product-in-this-c

Comment: Yes! it helped. thank you.

Comment: @eric, Can you also upvote?

Comment: Hi, upvote did.

Comment: Hi @eric, you have only accepted the answer. To upvote it, click the up arrow in front of the answer.

Comment: I did click the up arrow and it shows this "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: Okay, thanks @eric